# Windows server's task sheduler not working after few months

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, tasks

I am using windows task scheduler to run few tasks. But the tasks stop running time to time. May be after few months. Can I know why this happens?
dose this happen because of user password expiration?

Comment: Hello, please add further details, "tasks stop running" is too vague. Does it mean that tasks already running are terminated? What was needed to recover before it reoccured? Also please kindly fix the typos.

Comment: If a task is setup using a user password, and that password expires or changes, yes, that could stop a task from launching. In Task Scheduler, there's a tab that shows the eventlog. It will tell you why a task is failing. If your task is not using any networking resources, try using the user NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM (you can search for SYSTEM) so it launches as system user. Do test that your task works as expected though. Not all user privileges exists for user SYSTEM.